# Redirect React Router from function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am creating a React application using create-react-app, react-redux, react-thunk, react-router.

I am setting a localstorage variable "current_user" after authenticating so that I can setup my Restricted Routers.

I am using Axios to make the ajax requests, and In my initial index.js file I have setup a global Axios Interceptor so that if any ajax call returns 401, it automatically clears the local storage "current_user". I would like it to also redirect to /Login.

I'm able to do this the old fashioned way (ie window.location) however, is there a way to set this global function to redirect from anywhere in the application to the login page?

The global interceptor:

index.js

```
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from "axios";

import App from "./components/App";
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (error) {
  if(error.response.status === 401) {    //Setup Global Config
    localStorage.setItem('current_user', null);
   //Would like to redirect to /Login here
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';


const history = createHistory({
 window.location.pathname,
});

// ...

if(error.response.status === 401) {
   // ...
   history.push('/login');
}
```

Here you can find another approach to redirect your user if you don't have the token in the localStorage : https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/blob/master/login-react/react-login-front-end-app/app/containers/WithAuth/index.js

Comment: I tried this, and it updates the url in the browser but does not redirect the page..

Answer (score 0):

Just Use : `return <Redirect to="/login" />`. That should do.